# How to really log out from a PHP page

Tags: php

I have read similar ways to log out, but none of them seem to work for me. I Have used all this combinations on my logout.php page:

```
<?php 
session_start();
session_destroy();
$_SESSION = array();
$_SESSION['sec_session_id'] = "";
unset($_SESSION['session_name']);

echo '<script> window.location.assign("../index.php") </script>"'; //this line works fine
?>
```

But down the line, the only way to really log out is by closing the browser. Any ideas on what am I doing wrong?

Now, there´s another hope, making the cookie expire with  `setcookie("user", '', 1);` But I have no idea how to replace the word "user" :-/

Comment: you need to delete the session cookie, not some random OTHER cookie. But even if you delete the session cookie, you've already deleted all the session data by doing `$_SESSION = array()` so the user is effectively logged out anyways. The mere presence of an empty session should NEVER make a user "logged in".

Comment: So why is it that I can write the address of a php page intended only for logged users and I am able to open the page and navigate after logging out this way? The only way that the page denies my entry is if I have closed the browser and open it back again.

Comment: Probably because the page was cached by the browser. Try a forced-reload (e.g. shift-ctrl-R) which forces the browser to refetch the page and you'll get your "you are not logged in" stuff.

Comment: Nope :-s tried re-loading that way and nothing. As if the Session variables were still set! but how can this be possible, im going nuts...

Comment: then make sure that $_SESSION is actually being emptied. put a `var_dump($_SESSION)` onto each page and make sure you get a simple `Array()` output, instead of the contents that should have been removed.

Comment: I got it. The problem was that I must start my session the same way as the other pages, not just session_start() but the same name used on the other pages. Geez this gave me a head ache! LOL... thanks for your answers!!

Answer (score 1):

Please try this way...

```
//logout.php

//start session
session_start();

// clear session array
$_SESSION = array();

// if session set in cookie, force cookie to expire
if (isset($_COOKIE[session_name()]))
{
   $cookie_expires  = time() - date('Z') - 3600;
   setcookie(session_name(), '', $cookie_expires, '/');
}

// destroy session
session_destroy();

// redirection to your location
header("Location: /");
exit;
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, on my last comment I explained what I was doing wrong. Thank you for your answers!!